# Is it possible to fill upper left cell in wx.grid.Grid?

Tags: grid, wxpython

How this cell (up to row labels and left to column labels)
can be filled with text or image?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the wxPython demo that uses the GridLabelRenderer. Here's the relevant code from the demo:

```
class MyCornerLabelRenderer(glr.GridLabelRenderer):
    def __init__(self):
        import images
        self._bmp = images.Smiles.getBitmap()

    def Draw(self, grid, dc, rect, rc):
        x = rect.left + (rect.width - self._bmp.GetWidth()) / 2
        y = rect.top + (rect.height - self._bmp.GetHeight()) / 2
        dc.DrawBitmap(self._bmp, x, y, True)
```

Then you call it by doing something like this:

myGrid.SetCornerLabelRenderer(MyCornerLabelRenderer())